# JavaCompiler does not recognize dynamically loaded classes

Tags: java, jvm

I am facing a problem with compiling Java generated classes in-memory and I hope someone can point to where my problem is. I will simply the example and try to explain as easy as I can.

I have some code that is being generated that looks like this:

```java
package packOne;

public final class TestClassOne {
    public static String doSomething() {
        return "one";
    }
}
```

```java
package packTwo;

public final class TestClassTwo {
    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println(packOne.TestClassOne.doSomething());
    }
}
```

These are generated at runtime and I need to compile them and have them available. For this, I am using `JavaCompiler` in a `Compiler` class which (again, simplified) looks like this:

```java
public class Compiler {
    private final JavaCompiler javaCompiler;

    private final DynamicClassLoader dynamicClassLoader;
    private final DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics;
    private final ByteCodeGeneratingFileManager fileManager;

    public Compiler(DynamicClassLoader dynamicClassLoader) {
        this.dynamicClassLoader = dynamicClassLoader;
        this.javaCompiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        this.diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();
        this.fileManager = new ByteCodeGeneratingFileManager(javaCompiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null));
    }

    public byte[] compile(String className, String classContent) {
        // Compile the code
        JavaFileObject javaFileObject = new SourceCodeObject(className, classContent);
        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = javaCompiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, List.of(javaFileObject));
        Boolean result = task.call();
        if (result == null || !result) {
            throw new CompilationException(className, "Compilation failed.");
        }

        return fileManager.getBytecode();
    }

    public void load(String className, byte[] bytecode) {
        dynamicClassLoader.loadClass(className, bytecode);
    }
}
```

```java
public class DynamicClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    public Class<?> loadClass(String className, byte[] bytecode) {
        return defineClass(className, bytecode, 0, bytecode.length);
    }
}
```

```java
class ByteCodeGeneratingFileManager extends ForwardingJavaFileManager<JavaFileManager> {
        private ByteArrayOutputStream bytecode;

        ByteCodeGeneratingFileManager(JavaFileManager fileManager) {
            super(fileManager);
        }

        @Override
        public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(Location location, String className, JavaFileObject.Kind kind, FileObject sibling) {
            return new ByteCodeObject(className, kind);
        }

        public byte[] getBytecode() {
            return bytecode.toByteArray();
        }

        class ByteCodeObject extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
            ByteCodeObject(String name, JavaFileObject.Kind kind) {
                super(URI.create("bytecode:///" + name + kind.extension), kind);
            }

            @Override
            public OutputStream openOutputStream() {
                bytecode = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                return bytecode;
            }
        }
    }
```

I first compile the code for `TestClassOne` and than using the compiler I call `compiler.load("packOne.TestClassOne", byteCode)` to load the class. This Works as intended.

The problem is when I try to compile `TestClassTwo`. When I do this, I get the following error:
`error: package packOne does not exist`, just as if it does not recognize the first generated class. I am using the same compiler instance and hence the same fileManager instance.

Can anyone please let me know why is this happening and what would be a possible fix?

Comment: Seems like dynamicClassLoader does not know about your "TestClassOne" class when you are loading "TestClassTwo"  as there is no communication happening between class compilation logic and class loading logic.

Comment: The class loading for RunTime and Compilation is different; `compiler::load` makes a class available for execution, but not for the second compiler run.

Comment: @tquadrat I assumed that this is what is happening, especially since in my test I could execute the first class without any issues. However, I assumed that it would also be available if I used the same fileManager when doing compilation of the second, but this seems not to be the case. So, how can I work around this limitation?

Comment: `ByteCodeGeneratingFileManager` and `DynamicClassLoader` are not standard classes, so how are we supposed to know how they work? Of course, if the file manager provides the class generated in the first pass when the compiler asks for it in the second, it will work. But we do not know whether it even tries…

Comment: @Holger Updated the description with the two classes

Comment: Basically, the compiler has a "CLASSPATH", too, from where it get the classes to consider during the compilation. This will be initialised with the runtime CLASSPATH as it is at startup, but an update to the runtime CLASSPATH is not reflected to the compile "CLASSPATH" automatically. This CLASSPATH is provided basically through the `FileManager`, but unfortunately you create a new instance of it for each compiler run. If not, you overwrite the compiled `TestClassOne` in that second run, so that it is no longer available.

Comment: @tquadrat The file manager is created in the constructor of the `Compiler` class so if Petre reuses its instance (which I assumed from his first comment), there is only one file manager instance. However, in its current form it doesn’t hand out the class files to the compiler at all…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily retrace the problem with non-dynamic compilation, e.g. `javac` on the command line, when using a target directory as with the `-d` option. Compiling the second class in a separate pass will not find the class generated in the first pass, unless you add the output directory to the class path.

Since you’re not storing the generated classes in a directory you don’t have a directory to add to the class path. Instead, your custom file manager must be prepared to provide the stored class files when the compiler asks for it. But your file manager has the fundamental problem of not being designed to remember more than one class file. Likewise, your class loader is not prepared to provide classes on demand. So it will only work for the simplest incremental build as you’re trying now but, e.g. just having an inner class would already break it.

Therefore, the recommended steps are:

- Redesign the file manager to maintain a map from name to generated class file
- Change the `compile` method to return the class file from the file manager’s map matching the desired class, in case the source file produces more than one class file
- Override `getJavaFileForInput` to check whether the class is among the generated class files (and `kind == CLASS`) to return it (and delegate to `super` otherwise to find the predefined classes)
- Redesign the class loader to have a reference to the file manager and override `findClass`, to also check whether a class file for the requested name exists in the map and define and return the class (`findClass` will only be invoked for not-yet-defined classes)

Comment: Your answer pointed me to the right direction. With a bit of refactoring and improvements I managed to achieve what I was looking for. Instead of compiling each generated code in a seperate pass, I generated them and compiled all at once by passing all the JavaFileObjects. This solved the compilation problem. Thanks a lot for your help.